# Redirect user to facebook post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to display facebook wall post (by id) on my site in facebook style, or redirect user and focus him on current post at facebook. I`m already display it using open graph with my own css, but it should be look another way. In general i am interesting in second variant with ability redirect user on facebook and show him that post.
May be anyone know how to do that?

Thanks, Anton.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution, `https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=$POST_ID&id=$YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID`